Order of the components of the Specifications
Parts of an Application:

Title
Abstract
Drawings
Background of the Invention
Summary of the Disclosure
Brief Description of the Drawings
Detailed Description of the Invention
Claims

I got this directly from the uspto website.
In document, do the sections have to follow this EXACT order? In the document drafted by my attorney, they placed the abstract to the bottom for some reason.

In the published patent the abstract is first. In the application it is separate from the specification and can be thought of as last.
In this guide to filing at the USPTO the Abstract is last. Note that all the sections are not required. For example, no Summary of Invention is required and many practitioners no longer include that section.
For what is actually required you can refer to the MPEP, although it is complicated and convoluted it has the actual rules for examiners.
In an application the drawings are a separate file so there is no “order”. I think you are looking at the order of things in a published application or patent not information about filing an application.
